# QUICK SORT: Printing Memory Addresses instead of array elements:

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I have written the code for Quick-Sorting an array of integers, but upon printing it is showing kind of memory addresses on the terminal. I have been trying to figure out for a long time, but no sucess.

I have tried to compile it on online gdb compiler which gives an error: Segmentation Fault(core dumped), otherwise, I have tried to modify the code severalk times

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
int part(int arr[], int l, int r){    //for partioning the array
    int i=l, j=0;

    while(j<r){
            if(arr[j]<arr[r]){
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
                i++;
            }
        j++;
    }
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[r]);
return i;
}
void qsort(int arr[], int l, int r){    //recursive function for quicksort
    if(l<r){
        int p = part(arr, l, r);
        qsort(arr, l, p-1);
        qsort(arr, p+1, r);
    }
}
int main(void){
    int arr[] = {4, 10, 17, 5, 5, 6, 1 , 3, 0};

    qsort(arr, 0, 8);                 //function called

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){            
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);       //for printing the array
    }
return 0;
}
```

Actual Result:
 `11016472 1974520423 11016472 6356864 6 6356800 4214784 11015616 1974521024`
I was expecting the array to be sorted.

Comment: `qsort` is the name of a standard library function, and the behavior of defining it yourself is not defined by the C standard. Rename it and try again.

Comment: When I run this on my machine, it outputs `10 17 6 5 3 0 4 5 1`. Not quite sorted, but it's still the original values of the array.

Comment: @Eric Posypischil Have tried, still not working.

Comment: @scatter Yes, fewtimes I also got original values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil AFAIK it is no problem if you name a function equal to a function of the standard library. As long as you don't have incompatible declarations, the compiler will not moan. And the linker will use your function before looking for unresolved references in the libraries. However, it is **not recommended** to do so because at least you irritate everyone else reading your source. Can you give us a reference into the standard describing the undefined behaviour, please?

Comment: @thebusybee: C 2018 7.1.3 says the identifiers of the standard library are reserved, and 7.1.4 says that defining them other than as explicitly allowed has behavior not defined by the standard: “If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you very much! And so you are right, once more. :-) As a reviewer of source code I would not let such code pass, but for a toy program I'd rather think "Let her learn her lesson." And then concentrate at the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part, when `l` is greater than 0, starting `j` at 0 in `part` includes part of the array to the “left” of `l` in processing and may result in `i` (which was initialized to `l`) being incremented too many times, past `r`.

Changing `int i=l, j=0;` to `int i=l, j=l;` results in the program printing the desired output for the case in the question.

This problem could have been found by modifying `qsort` and `part` to print their parameters each time they are called, and to either print when they return or to indent the previous printing by the current recursion depth (which can be tracked, for debugging purposes, with a static counter). This promptly reveals a call to `qsort` with `r` set to 9, beyond the array, which then leads to examining how it came to be that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `j` to `l`, not `0`, upon entering `part`:

```
...
int part(int arr[], int l, int r){    //for partioning the array
    int i=l, j=l;

    while(j<r){ // line 10
...
```

If you don't do this, you will end up reading (and possibly writing) past the bounds of array when `r` is greater than `8`.

Answer (score 1):

Your partitioning is broken. It appears to be loosely based on two algorithms, neither of which you implemented correctly.

```
int part(int arr[], int l, int r){    //for partitioning the array
```

this tells us we have some array and we want to partition the range between `l` and `r`. It isn't clear whether that goal is *inclusive* of those indexes, but it doesn't really matter because the subsequent code is broken anyway.

```
int i=l, j=0; // HERE. Why is j 0 ??
```

Later on, you access `arr[j]` multiple times, both read and write. If the range you're partitioning is in [l..r], there is no guarantee whatsoever that `j`, starting at zero, is in that range. Starting `j` at `l` is appropriate.

But there's a better way.

First, this is C. Within `part` the id `arr` isn't an array; it's a *pointer*. Let us suppose we have a sequence where the `l` is always starting at zero, and the `r` is simply the length. In that case the `l` argument would be fairly pointless, and our `part` function could just start like this:

```
int part(int arr[], int len)
```

Fair enough. Now we can implement a simple partition that chooses a pivot, partitions based on that pivot, and returns the index of where the pivot ended up. I'll not go in to the related topic of choosing a "good" pivot. There are several approaches, and I encourage you to investigate yourself. In the interest of simplicity we'll use a right-most-element pivot for this example:

```
int part(int arr[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 0;

    int pvt = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[len-1]) 
            swap(arr+i, arr + pvt++);
    }
    swap(arr+pvt, arr+len-1);

    return pvt;
}
```

Simple enough. Now how does this help the actual quick sort?  It helps by using the offset address as the lead argument when partitioning the sequence. It also helps because now we can do to `q_sort` the same thing we did to `part`, namely get rid of one of the arguments and just use a base address and length:

```
void q_sort(int arr[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    int p = part(arr, len);
    q_sort(arr, p);
    q_sort(arr+p+1, len-p-1);
}
```

That's it. Note the second recursive call uses pointer arithmetic to position the base-address of the target sequence at one-past the pivot location. The length is adjusted accordingly.

The full program appears below, including a test harness that generates a 30 element sequence, then sorts and displays the results:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int part(int arr[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 0;

    int pvt = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[len-1])
            swap(arr+i, arr + pvt++);
    }
    swap(arr+pvt, arr+len-1);

    return pvt;
}

void q_sort(int arr[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    int p = part(arr, len);
    q_sort(arr, p);
    q_sort(arr+p+1, len-p-1);
}

#define N_ELEMS     30

int main(void)
{
    int arr[N_ELEMS];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N_ELEMS; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = 1 + (rand() % 99);
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);


    q_sort(arr, N_ELEMS);

    for (int i=0; i<N_ELEMS; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
21 95 18 10 57 60 60 6 37 72 44 99 91 25 14 5 50 58 16 18 81 5 52 42 15 40 58 16 76 61 
5 5 6 10 14 15 16 16 18 18 21 25 37 40 42 44 50 52 57 58 58 60 60 61 72 76 81 91 95 99
```

The benefits here are two fold. First, there is no requirement the initial caller provide both ends of a sequence. Second, the functions are actually *simpler*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't strictly quick sort though, is it? It doesn't follow the normal (the OP's code with `j` as `l`) convention for it. (this is meant as a legitimate question, not rhetorical)

Comment: It is quicksort. The partition mechanics are generally one of two forms. This is the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme), and is often used when teaching the overall techniques of divide and conquer, and quicksort, because it is so trivial to understand.

Answer (score -3):

The first time you call part() 'i' will never be incremented since no value is less than arr[8].  The function will return 'i' which is 0.  You then call qsort(arr, l,p - 1 (which is -1)).  At this point you will be swapping with arr[-1]. Most of the values of the arr array will be be swapped with random data from the stack due to the incorrect indices.  That is why you getting the strange values.

```
int part(int arr[], int l, int r){    //for partioning the array
int i=l, j=0;

while(j<r){
        if(arr[j]<arr[r]){
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
    j++;
}
swap(&arr[i], &arr[r]);
return i;
}
```

Comment: Did you change the code?  It looks like you just re-posted op's buggy code.

Comment: The body of `qsort` is wrapped in `if(l<r)`. If it is called with `qsort(arr, l, p-1);` with `l` equal to 0 and `p` equal to −1, then it receives 0 for `l` and −2 for `r`, and `l<r` is false, so it does nothing.